# Programmatically scrolling a Windows edit control

Tags: windows, winapi, scroll, editcontrol

Is there any way to programmatically scroll a single-line edit control in Windows?

For example, if the text in an edit control is too large to display at once, then the default behavior when the edit control gets the focus is to select all text and show the end of the text.  I'd like to instead show the beginning of the text (while still leaving all text selected).

Comment: That's not the default bahaviour. The control (or it's sub class) must be explicitly selecting all the text on focus.

Comment: @Deanna - Are you sure about that?  I remember seeing the select-all-on-focus behavior since the Windows 95 days; I'm certain that it is the default behavior.

Comment: Most of the Windows Shell seem to do it, but I've not seen it on "native" win32 apps, and MSDN doesn't say it does it on `WM_GOTFOCUS`, just shows the existing selection. I may be completely wrong though :) (I can't compile any C++ stuff atm :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's (apparently) no API for scrolling to the beginning and selecting all text, it seems to work to simulate the keystrokes that would do the same:

```
#ifndef CTRL               
#define CTRL(x) (x&037)    
#endif

SendMessage(edit_handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_HOME, 0);
SendMessage(edit_handle, WM_CHAR, CTRL('A'), 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either call [SetScrollPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or send the [WM_VSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[WM_HSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message directly to the window. You can find the full list of scroll functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486021%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I've tried this, and I can't get it to work for a stock single-line edit control.  SetScrollPos fails with ERROR_NO_SCROLLBARS.

Comment: Ah, missed the part about single-line edit control. That control would not have a scrollbar at all then.

Comment: Have you tried `Edit_SetSel`/`EM_SETSEL` with start value as the end (length) and end value as 0?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Edit_SetSel(h, length, 0)` doesn't work either.  (In fact, it seems to act the same as `Edit_SetSel(h, 0, length)`, which is strange, since that's not how MSDN describes it.)

Comment: "Edit controls: The control displays a flashing caret at the end position regardless of the relative values of start and end." - This explains why it doesn't work.